# Visual Studio Exclude Project on Build Configuration // Where are these "unchecks" persisted to file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

This URL talks about how to exclude a project from a solution build, using checkboxes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676765.aspx

Which I've done a thousand times.

Now our Build Server is building solutions that I have "unchecked".

Now I'm trying to fish where the "checkbox" settings are persisted.

Does anyone know where the check/uncheck settings get persisted?

In the .sln file?  Or sibling file?  I can't find it.

The .sln file not being xml has me suspecting it is some weird suffix on a certain line or something.

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought of this sooner.

I made a copy of my .sln file.

I did some "unchecking" in the Configuration Manager (under the menu item "Build"/"Configuration Manager")

I saved the .sln

I did a winmerge comparision with the copy.

The magic line seems to be "Build.0".

Before

```
  {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
  {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
   {BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
```

After:

```
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{BBBBBBBB-AAAA-1111-2222-333333333333}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
```

That's what I found after 20 minutes.  Maybe it can help a future reader, so I'm leaving the question up....